# Php multiply price with total hours

Tags: php

I have to multiple total numbers of hours `eg: 13:15` with a price like `500`.

Example:

```
$hours=13:15;
$price=500;
$result=$hours*$price;
$result=???
```

How can I multiple total numbers of hours with the price to get the final price??

Comment: This doesn't make any more sense now than the last time you posted it... `13:15` is a specific time not a period unless you mean 13 hours and 15 minutes?

Comment: @Gulshan your are right, split your time value on the ":" character and divide the minute portion by 60 and add to the hour value. 13 + 15/60 = 13,25

Comment: Your problem is: "How can i convert minutes to hours?" which is an already answered question.

Comment: @Gulshan An answer un-accepted 7 months later! Any explanation as to why?

Answer (score 8):

Something like this:

```
<?php
    $hours='13:15';

    list($h, $m) = explode(':',$hours);  //Split up string into hours/minutes
    $decimal = $m/60;  //get minutes as decimal
    $hoursAsDecimal = $h+$decimal;


    $price=500;
    $result=$hoursAsDecimal*$price;

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to separate hours and minutes from the string, then convert minutes to hours. Add the converted hours to extracted hours and multiply by price. Something like this,

```
$hours='13:15';
$time = explode(':', $hours);
if(count($time) != 2)
    throw new Exception("Invalid value!");
$hr = $time[0] + ($time[1] / 60);

$price=500;
$result=$hr*$price;
echo $result;
```

Answer (score -3):

use a . instead of :

```
$hours=13:15;

$hours=13.15;
```

Comment: 15 minutes = 0.25 hours.